# libglade2.0 version not compatible

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, gtk3, glade, glib

I was trying to install phoebe-gui. When I'm trying to do. ./configure the error is showing "cannot find libglade2.0"  Even though it is installed in my system. (I'm getting errors in fedora and ubuntu)

Can someone help me resolve this... Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provided OS/product/release details; and what package did you install?  The `.configure` implies you're compiling to me, which requires the -dev package to be installed, not runtime *binary*, but you've given no actual specifics.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.